# Php class method not being called

Tags: php

I have a problem with my PHP class, when the user wants to follow another user the follow method is called and when the user wants to stop following the `delete_follow` is called:

```
class Follow {

    protected static $table_name = "interests";


    public function follow() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".self::$table_name." (company_id,user_id,likedate) VALUES (:company_id,:user_id,NOW())";
        $follow = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $follow->bindParam(':user_id',$_SESSION['user_id']);
        $follow->bindParam(':company_id',$_GET['company']);
        if($follow->execute() == true){
            header("Location: profile.php?company=".$_GET['company']."");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: error.php");
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function delete_follow() {
        global $dbh;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE company_id = :company_id AND user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1";
        $delete_follow = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $delete_follow->bindParam(':user_id',$_SESSION['user_id']);
        $delete_follow->bindParam(':company_id',$_GET['company']);
        if($delete_follow->execute() == true) {
            header("Location: profile.php?company=".$_GET['company']."");
            exit;
        } else {
            header("Location: error.php");
            exit;
        }
    }   


}
```

My problem is that when the delete_follow method is called it actually calls the follow method I have no idea what is going on.

Here is the code for the follow buttons:

```
if(isset($_POST['follow'])) {
    $follows = new Follow();
    $follows->follow();
}

if(isset($_POST['delete_follow'])) {
    $follows = new Follow();
    $follows->delete_follow();
}
```

Help please.

Answer (score 4):

The name of your class is `Follow`. The first method in your class is called `follow()`. PHP is case insensitive in this aspect and treats that `follow()` method as the constructor. So this statement--`$follows = new Follow()`--actually calls the `follow()` method from your class. Therein could lie your problem.

Read more about PHP constructors [here](http://ralphschindler.com/2012/03/09/php-constructor-best-practices-and-the-prototype-pattern).

Comment: No. The constructor is __construct()

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, "For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class." http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @Cole Johnson: In PHP, constructors can be both the new `__construct()` method or the name of the class itself. Look here, example 2: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that there is an error in your form. Perhaps it would be better to have one field `follow` with a boolean value, say `yes` or `no`.

Comment: It's not the form, becasue before I had the code in a normal function and it worked fine, when I moved it to a class the problem occured